# Develop a mobile game for all platforms

Tags: mobile, game-engine

I want to develop a mobile game app. Is there any tool that i should use so that i don't have to remake it again and again for different platforms available?
Also performance is a issue and should be easy to learn.

Comment: If performance is a issue I say no. For performance you always want native code for the platform. There are some frameworks for writting apps once for multiple devices but they mostly use web technologies to achieve that. I know none that are suiteable for games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn OpenGL it graphics library for all platform 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL

its having good performance but learning curve is more. Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering using an engine, with the benefit of writing your code once and then publish it to all platforms, have a look [V-Play](http://v-play.net/).

The engine core is written in native C++, combined with the custom renderer, the games reach a solid performance of 60fps across all devices.

V-Play also comes with ready-to-use game templates for the most successful game genres like tower defense, platform games or puzzle games, several tutorials and demos. ([V-Play examples & demos](http://v-play.net/doc/daily/))
([API reference](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-group.html))

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the guys behind V-Play)